# Kafka 0.9.0.x installed through "brew install kafka" is built for Scala 2.10 or 2.11?

Tags: scala, homebrew, apache-kafka

Apache Kafka download page says that it's available for Scala 2.10 and 2.11.

If I have installed Kafka using "brew install kafka" (on MacOS X) then which build is installed - for 2.10 or for 2.11?

I'm planning to use it together with Spark (currently 1.6.1, using Scala 2.10 if we don't want to build it ourselves) and I want a uniform version of Scala for all, within one project.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.9.0.0/libexec/core/build/libs/kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0.jar`

`2.10` stands for Scala version.